# What does `\` mean at the beginning of an ADT alternative?

Tags: rascal

From http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/lang/java/m3/TypeSymbol/Bound/Bound.html:

```
data Bound 
   = \super(list[TypeSymbol] bound)
   | \extends(list[TypeSymbol] bound)
   | \unbounded()
   ;
```

Is there any specific reason why all the alternatives start with a `\`? What does this mean? Is this some sort of convention or is it special Rascal syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to escape identifiers.

Say you want to name a constructor (or function) `if`, this would overlap with the `if` statement (and is therefore reserved).

If you put a `\` in front of an identifier, you escape the name. Just like a `\"` inside a string literal.

Now, for the Java AST, the choice was made for alignment. Instead of:

```
| method(...)
| \if(...)
| variable(...)
```

You add a `\` in front of every alternative.

Comment: Some people escape all names of the constructors, if only one of them needs it (in this case `\this` and `\super`) for textual alignment purposes.